# How can I throttle the network calls that some of my tmux plugins make?

Tags: bash, caching, curl, tmux

I have a couple of tmux scripts, that display information like ip, time, hostname, etc in my tmux statusbar. For example, the ip script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

runSegment() {
  # check for a network connection
  nc -z 8.8.8.8 53  >/dev/null 2>&1
  online=$?

  if [ $online -eq 0 ]; then
    # get ip
    ip=`curl icanhazip.com`
    echo -n "  ${ip}"
  else
    echo ""
  fi
}

export -f runSegment
```

It checks for a network connection and gets the ip if there is one. Now my tmux statusbar is set to refresh every five seconds (`tmux set-option -g status-interval 5`). But making network requests to these services every five seconds seems a little excessive.

However, I'd like to keep stuff like battery status and time updated every five seconds, so setting the status-interval to five minutes or so is not an option.

So how do I get this script to return a cached value, and only after five minutes or so refresh that value? I'm assuming I need to solve this in bash, but I'd need to have internal state for that, and as this script gets run anew every time I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Have you thought about maintaining the required state by using a file (e.g. that would contain a time stamp of when the last successful attempt was made)?

Comment: @Fred Yeah seems like that would be the way to go. Could I save both the timestamp and retrieved value in the file, or would it be smarter to save them to separate files?

Comment: You can just use the modification time of the file as the timestamp.

Comment: @ismay There probably are many ways to achieve that...  You could use `date +%s` to generate a time stamp as an integer (in seconds), easy to deal with.  Whether you use one file or two, that really is up to you...  Two files keeps parsing to a minimum.  @Barmar Is there an easy way to get the times stamp in a format that makes duration calculations easy?  If so, that would be only one file yet still no parsing.

Comment: You can use the `stat` command to get the modification time as a number, and the `date` command to get the current time as a number, then see if the current time is at least the mtime+300.

Comment: @ismay I am sorry, but I do not know the utilities you use well enough to provide reliable feedback without actual testing or research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this works:

```
#!/bin/bash

runSegment() {
  # check if online and assign exit code to variable
  nc -z 8.8.8.8 53  >/dev/null 2>&1
  local online=$?

  if [ $online -eq 0 ]; then
    # check how many seconds ago ip was retrieved
    local lastmod=$(( $(date +%s) - $(stat -f%c ~/.current-ip) ))

    # if longer than five minutes ago refresh the value and echo that
    if [ $lastmod -gt 300 ]; then
      local ip=$(curl icanhazip.com)
      echo ${ip} > $HOME/.current-ip
      echo -n "  ${ip}"

    # otherwise use the cached value
    else
      local ip=$(cat $HOME/.current-ip)
      echo -n "  ${ip}"
    fi

  # return empty value if there's no connection
  else
    echo ""
  fi
}

export -f runSegment
```

Comment: In your `lastmod=echo ...` line, the `echo` and backticks are redundant.  Just keep `=$((...))`.  Also, generally speaking, you could prefer using `$(command)` instead of backticks for readability purposes (though backticks are valid too).